# group by date and show the values of X(column) which depends on min time of that date and max time of that date in 1 row

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have table like

```
id  u_id     date       time      x
---|-----|------------|--------|-----
1  | 1   | 20200806   | 0900   | 60 
2  | 2   | 20200806   | 0905   | 60 
3  | 3   | 20200806   | 0910   | 61 
4  | 1   | 20200806   | 1015   | 62 
5  | 1   | 20200806   | 1830   | 61 
6  | 3   | 20200807   | 0915   | 61 
7  | 1   | 20200807   | 0920   | 62 
8  | 2   | 20200807   | 1820   | 63 
9  | 1   | 20200807   | 1835   | 59
```

I want to
group by date
which user has
the id of u_id =1
and get first time and value of x
and get the last time and value of x
in same row

it should be like

```
   date       firstTime  firstX   lastTime   lastX
   -----------|----------|--------|----------|----------
   20200806   |   0900   |   60   |   1830   | 61
   20200807   |   0920   |   62   |   1835   | 59
```

what i've tried

```
select
            p.created_date as date,
            min(p.created_time) as firstTime,
            max(p.created_time) as lastTime,
from
     passes as p
where
      p.id=1
group by p.created_date;
```

but i cant get the values of xs.

the rows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select p.created_date as date,
       min(p.created_time) as firstTime,
       max(p.created_time) as lastTime,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then x end) as first_x,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then x end) as last_x,
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by created_time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by created_time desc) as seqnum_desc
      from passes p
     ) p
where p.id=1
group by p.created_date;
```

You can also phrase the conditional aggregation as:

```
       max(x) filter where (seqnum = 1) as first_x,
       max(x) filter where (seqnum_desc = 1) as last_x,
```

Another method uses arrays:

```
select p.created_date as date,
       min(p.created_time) as firstTime,
       max(p.created_time) as lastTime,)
       (array_agg(p.x order by p.created_date asc))[1] as first_x,
       (array_agg(p.x order by p.created_date desc))[1] as last_x
from passes p
where p.id = 1
group by p.created_date;
```

Comment: min(case when seqnum = 1 then temperature end) as first_x then works. Thanks a lot !

Comment: what about boolean columns?

Comment: @BertanCakici . . . You would need to use `bool_or()` or `bool_and()`.  Or for a common expression `(array_agg(x) filter (where seqnum = 1))[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `first_value()` and `last_value()` window functions to achieve this:

```
select distinct 
       "date", 
       first_value(time) over w as first_time,
       first_value(x) over w as first_x,
       last_value(time) over w as last_time,
       last_value(x) over w as last_x
  from passes
 where u_id = 1
window w as (partition by u_id
                 order by date
          rows between unbounded preceding
                   and unbounded following);
```

[Working Fiddle Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nufPv4928dMhXei3aiX8tV/1)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your results by creating a subquery. The subquery group values by date and return the first and last time.

By having the date, first and last times, I did two joins, one to grab that firstX and another to grab the lastX.

by using mySQL as the engine, I did these steps on http://sqlfiddle.com/:

Build Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE passes
    (`id` int, `u_id` int, `date` int, `time` int, `x` int)
;
INSERT INTO passes
    (`id`, `u_id`, `date`, `time`, `x`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 20200806, 0900, 60),
    (2, 2, 20200806, 0905, 60),
    (3, 3, 20200806, 0910, 61),
    (4, 1, 20200806, 1015, 62),
    (5, 1, 20200806, 1830, 61),
    (6, 3, 20200807, 0915, 61),
    (7, 1, 20200807, 0920, 62),
    (8, 2, 20200807, 1820, 63),
    (9, 1, 20200807, 1835, 59)
;
```

MySQL query:

```
Select SUB1.TheDate,SUB1.firstTime,x1.x as firstX,SUB1.lastTime,x2.x as lastX from 
(select
      passes.date as TheDate,
      min(passes.time) as firstTime,
      max(passes.time) as lastTime
from passes
where
  passes.u_id = 1
group by passes.date) AS SUB1

join passes as x1 
on x1.date = SUB1.TheDate
and x1.time = SUB1.firstTime

join passes as x2 
on x2.date = SUB1.TheDate
and x2.time = SUB1.lastTime
```

The result looked like this:

```
TheDate     firstTime   firstX  lastTime    lastX
20200806    900         60      1830        61
20200807    920         62      1835        59
```